# Using openFileDialog in WFA

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I have done WFA using `openFileDialog`, I want to choose the path for my files and store it in variables, then I want to run/execute my compare program, (but I need to control it; if we have a path it will run), here's where I don't know how I can do it, I need help please.

I tried to put it is Always hope to `messagebox`:

```
private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( defaultFilePath == openFileDialog1.FileName 
      && alternativeFilePath == openFileDialog1.FileName
      && resultFilePath == openFileDialog1.FileName )
    {
        Compare_D_A d_A = new Compare_D_A();
        d_A.CompareD_A(defaultFilePath, alternativeFilePath, resultFilePath);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to Choose File path!");
    }
}
```

I want to choose the first file path by `button_1 click`,and another file path in `button_2 click`, and the third file path in `button_3 click`. If I choose all file paths it will run the program, else `messagebox`, I tried with a breakpoint but it seems the  `openFileDialog1` always saves the last path only, so I get the `Messagebox`, What should be done to correct this problem? I'm new to WFA so please try to understand my question.

Comment: use variables/array/list to store the result of each file dialog box

Comment: can you show me in code how I do that?

Comment: something like `MyVar = ...`

Comment: how I can do if here? I have wrote this code,                                                         string arr [] = new string [3]; arr[0]= path1; arr[1] = path2; arr[2] = path3; Then I want if all path sexists run program,

Comment: In each of your click methods where you open the file dialog, you get the opened path and store it in a property of the class

Comment: You can use : FolderBrowserDialog